# Reciprocal of sin(x)

Tags: trigonometry

What is the reciprocal of sin(x), or what is 1/sin(x) equal to in terms of trigonometric ratios? Please answer simply, as I am a high school student, not a mathematician.

Comment: Say you have an angle $x$ (which is acute) inside a right triangle. Then $sin(x)=\frac{\mbox{opp}}{\mbox{hyp}}$, then $\frac{1}{\sin x}$ (which is called $\csc x$, the cosecant), would be $\frac{\mbox{hyp}}{\mbox{opp}}$, this would probably work for a high student...

Comment: You may also find it useful to notice that due to $\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$, $\sin(x)=\tan(x)\cos(x)$ (And, as a result. . .) $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}=\frac{1}{\tan(x)\cos(x)}=\cot(x)\sec(x)$.

You can find more than enough information at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions

Much of trigonometry is founded in repetition of the same thing in different ways.

Comment: $$r = \frac{a}{b} \iff \frac{1}{r} = \frac{b}{a}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you said it's $\dfrac{1}{\sin x}$, you've already got a "trigonometric ratio".  It's also equal to $\dfrac{\sec x}{\tan x}$.  Or you can say it's $\dfrac{\text{hypotenuse}}{\text{opposite}}$.  All of those are ratios.